# As setas de votações sumiram?

Tags: suporte, bug, interface-usuário

As setas de votações não estão aparecendo, ***observe***:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

fui olhar no console do navegador e tem um **erro**:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse problema é geral?

**Observação:** no meta não acontece o mesmo problema.

Comment: Aqui esta normal. Estou acessando do Google Chrome.

Comment: @gato estranho eu também acesso do Google Chrome, pode ser cache?

Comment: veja se o msm problema ocorre no navegador anônimo. Mas, pode ser cache sim.

Comment: @gato sim acontece...!!!

Comment: Aqui está normal

Comment: Tá normal pra mim também.

Comment: Use outro navegador e outra banda de internet, se possível, pra testar. Pode ser algum problema na rede local. Já aconteceu comigo em outra situação...

Comment: Este erro `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED` me faz pensar que só pode ser duas coisas, ou é um proxy na sua rede ou algo add-on no Chrome.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento estou investigando eu estou achando que é o proxy da operadora de internet pelo visto, mas, como não tenho certeza deixei em aberto, já visto que outro amigo da comunidade aconteceu algo parecido.

Comment: Então, geralmente os servidores compactam as respostas e enviam o header `Accept-Encoding` com o formato da compactação, o proxy pode estar descompactando mas mantendo o header erroneamente, se você tiver programas como WireShark ou até mesmo wget você conseguirá depurar.